# Поиск совпадений строке

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как я могу найти совпадение в строке через связанную таблицу?

```
DECLARE @tableA TABLE (
    Id              INT
    ,ConcatMaker    NVARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT  @tableA (Id
                ,   ConcatMaker)
VALUES (1, N'RU, US, UN');

DECLARE @tableB TABLE (
    ID      INT
    ,Maker  NVARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT  @tableB (ID
                ,   Maker)
VALUES (1, N'RU')
    ,(1, N'EU')
    ,(1, N'GB');
```

Единственный вариант, который я нашел это использование CHARINDEX, но он мне не совсем подходит, потому что он проверяет каждое значение по очереди:

```
SELECT      CASE
                WHEN CHARINDEX(b.Maker, a.ConcatMaker) <> 0
                    THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END AS Result
FROM        @tableA AS a
INNER JOIN  @tableB AS b
    ON b.ID = a.Id;
```

И в результате я получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А хочу получить 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к я использую старую версию SQL server, то я не смог воспользоваться функцией "string_split", поэтому пришлось писть функцию вручную. Нечто подобное я нашел в [этом посте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string).

Comment: [Здесь](http://blogs.rsdn.ru/sql/6380659) собраны варианты string_split с замерами производительности. PS: код не открывается по нажатию на плюсик, но в сорсах html он есть.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с версии 2017 (Функция [string_split](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_string_split_function.html)):

```
select b.maker from 
(select id, ltrim(value) maker from @tableA cross apply string_split(ConcatMaker,',')) X
join @tableB B on b.id=x.id and b.maker=x.maker;
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую Ваш вариант